# My PHP file will not calculate user input and won't output paragraph?

Tags: php, html

Why won't " **$total_pizza_size = $pizza_size;** and 
                **$total_toppings = $toppings * 1.25;**" calculate? I made my variable in the beginning of this program and it keeps getting the error **"Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles....php on line 50"**

The paragraphs at the bottom also will not show up when i run the program. What is happening?

```
*<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your Pizza Order</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
        <h3>Your Pizza Order</h3><?php

    $pizza_size = array (
        "pizza_size"  => array("medium" => 7, "large" => 9, "family" => 9));

            //size
        $size = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'size');
            echo "You selected size $size @ <br>";

            //toppings
          $toppings = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'toppings',
                    FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS,FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);

            if($toppings != NULL) {
                $num_toppings = count($toppings);
                echo "<br>You chose these $num_toppings toppings @ $1.25 each<br>";
                foreach($toppings as $key => $value) {
                    echo "$value<br>";
                }
            }
            //other items
            $other_items = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'other_items',
                    FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);

            if ($other_items !== NULL) {
                $num_other_items = count($other_items);
                //echo $key. ' = ' . $value . '<br>';
                echo "<br>You also chose extras $num_other_items @ $1.50 each<br>";
                foreach ($other_items as $key2 => $value2) {
                }
            } 

            //request
            $request = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'request');
            $request = nl2br($request,false);
            if($request != '') {
                echo "<br>You made this request:<br>";
                echo $request;
            }

            $total_pizza_size = $pizza_size;
            $total_toppings = $toppings * 1.25;
            $total_other_items = $other_items * 1.50;
            $total = $total_pizza_size + $total_other_items + $total_toppings;
            $total_f ='$'.number_format($total, 2);
            ?>

    <p>Your total amount due on delivery is <?php echo $total_f;  ?></p>
    <p>Your pizza will be delivered
    to:</p><span><?php echo $address_one; ?></span><br>
    <h2>Thanks for ordering from the Pizza Place</h2>
    <p>We will call <span><?php echo $phone_number; ?></span><br></p>
```

*

Comment: I think 5 answers saying you can't use an array like a number will do the job. Just in case someone else wants to add an answer. Gosh.

Answer (score 0):

You can not sum whole arrays. You have to iterate through array items...

```
foreach ($pizza_size as $key => $value) {
 .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like $toppings is an array, that it probably where you made the misstake.
perhaps array_sum($toppings) * 1.25 ?

Answer (score 0):

`$pizza_size` is defined as array, not as integer/real.

You have to change your code like this:

```
$total_pizza_size = $pizza_size['pizza_size']['medium'];
```

(edited:)

```
$total_pizza_size = $pizza_size['pizza_size'][$size];
```

if I understand your code.

I don't known the kind of value passed to `$toppings`

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph at the bottom does not show up because you have a syntax error above. The script exits.

Try:

$total_toppings = count($toppings) * 1.25

and

$total_pizza_size = $size

You can not multiply a scalar value (1.25) X an array ($toppings). The $total_pizza_size has same problem. You need to use the selected size not the whole array.